# apache does not allow access to system fonts

Tags: django, apache

I'm running a django 1.8 app on apache 2.4.6.
As soon as I try to import matplotlib, it fails due to permission problems accessing system fonts.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 27, in <module>
import matplotlib.colorbar
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
import matplotlib.collections as collections
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 27, in <module>
import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 56, in <module>
import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 19, in <module>
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1415, in <module>
_rebuild()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1400, in _rebuild
fontManager = FontManager()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1055, in __init__
self.ttflist = createFontList(self.ttffiles)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 580, in createFontList
font = ft2font.FT2Font(fpath)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/usr/share/fonts/MyFont/some_font.ttf'
```

I have these permissions

```
755 /usr/
755 /usr/share/
755 /usr/share/fonts/
775 /usr/share/fonts/MyFont/
755 /usr/share/fonts/MyFont/*

<Directory /usr/share/fonts">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

It's trying to cache the font in the home durectory at /home/apache/.cache/matplotlib
so I created the /home/apache folder and changed the ownership to apache.
It still fails.

How can this be fixed while being able to load my font?

Comment: Your django user should have appropriate permissions on all parent folders as well, which is `/usr/`, `/usr/share/`.

Comment: I can run django fine as another user, but it does not work on apache. Apache runs as apache user. I've listed the parent folder permissions above. Also, I cannot switch user to apache because I get an error "This account is currently not available."